# What is the optimal image format for display in a UIImageView control?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

I have images on a server that will be downloaded and displayed in a UIImageView control. What is the optimal image format for these images, .jpg, .png, etc? I want to minimize the d/l time and also have the best quality images displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PNG is pretty much the standard. They're already zipped and are lossless.